# Efficient way to solve "CountFactors" codility question

Tags: javascript

I have been running through Codility questions and and one of the questions was to count all the possible factors of a number. I looped through the whole number got the answer but it wasn't efficient of course.

I searched for the answer and got this

```
function solution(N) {
  var i;
    var NumFactors = 0;

    for(i = 1;i*i < N; i++) {
        if(N%i == 0) NumFactors += 2;
    }

    if(i*i == N) NumFactors++;

    return NumFactors
}
```

for anyone who hasn't tried the challenge if you run `solution(24)` it should return 8 as number of factors which are (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8,12, 24)

Since the person who wrote the code didn't leave any explanation, can someone who get what's happening kindly explain to me the `i*i` and the reason of incrementing NumFactors by 2.

Answer (score 3):

The `i*i` is for checking until squareRoot(N). Because if you have a divisor for a number N then you actually have two divisor. Because the division result is another divisor. For example, in case of 24,

If you take divisor 2, you will find another divisor which is 12. Because `2 X 12 = 24`. If you loop through N i.e. 1 to 24 you will get the divisors like this,

```
2 X 12 = 24
3 X 8 = 24
4 X 6 = 24
6 X 4 = 24
8 X 3 = 24
12 X 2 = 24
24 X 1 = 24
```

You see we have got redundant values after squareRoot(N). That is why for optimization we are going from 1 to squareRoot(N).

Now about increase factors by 2 is already described above. For the special case when N is a perfect square number like 36 or 49 you will face a case where `6 X 6 = 36` and `7 X 7 = 49` that is why in that case we are increasing the factor by one. Because there is actually on divisor namely `6` and `7` in our case.